# Getting webpage title regex

Tags: regex, preg-match

I am not good with regex;

I am trying to read webpage titles.I have encountered some pages with structures like `<title itemprop="name">test - Google+</title>` OR `<title id="name">Safaricom - Google+</title>`

When i try reading them with the below code i get untitled,how can i fix this.

```
$header_data = Array(); 
if (preg_match("@<title *>(.*?)<\/title*>@si", $file, $header_data)) {
        $title = trim($header_data[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the use of *

- indicates that the preceding regex/character can be present 0 or many times

so this is trying to match a space many times and will ONLY allow for spaces after title and between >

try

```
<title.*>(.*?)<\/title>
```

Comment: thank you ...i have tested this but it is still not working

Comment: @Andreas Sorry i was using this preg_match("@<title.*>(.*?)<\/title*>@si", $file, $header_data) instead of preg_match("/<title.*>(.*)<\/title>/", $file, $header_data);